# Can a high density of particles simulate fluid dynamics?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, rigid-body-dynamics

There are different ways to simulate fluids, some involve numerical solutions to PDEs. I was wondering if these PDE formulations can be thought of as an a infinite limit of a collection of particles? In particular can a high density of particles simulate fluid flow?

How would you compare numerically solving a PDE to running a rigid body dynamic simulation involving a high density of particles?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are methods in computational fluid dynamics which model fluid flow by following the motion of conceptual neutrally buoyant particles within the fluid. These methods come under the headings of [discrete element methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_element_method), [smoothed particle hydrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothed-particle_hydrodynamics) and [Lagrangian particle tracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_particle_tracking). These methods are computationally expensive, but useful in scenarios where numerical solution of the underlying PDEs is inefficient e.g. turbulent flow or flows with complicated boundaries.

Comment: This answer is largely correct, but Lagrangian particle tracking is not used to simulate the fluid, it's used to simulate additional phases within a fluid (solid particles or liquid droplets for example). You could also add [Particle-in-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle-in-cell) type methods, which is a hybrid method I suppose.

Comment: And [dissipative particle dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissipative_particle_dynamics) also falls in this category, which can bridge the gap from molecular dynamics to continuum mechanics.